# How to generate link to posted post to wordpress in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress, eventmachine

I have the following task:

User enter some keyword and than text, for example "CODE "some code"". I need to post this code "some code" to my wordpress account to a specific category, and than give link to that post in chatroom.
This must be done using eventmachine.

I found ways to post to wordpress. http://rcbth.com/2010/07/16/wordpress-posting-from-ruby-xmlrpc/ and https://github.com/cjbottaro/em-xmlrpc-client to make this compatible with eventmachine. But I can't guess how to generate a proper link to that post.

Sorry for my bad english.